# Add sequence number to items from mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I have MongoDB collection `items` with following documents:

```
{ "name": "First", "value": 8 },
{ "name": "Second", "value": 2 },
{ "name": "Third", "value": 5 }
```

I would like to sort them by `name` or `value` and then add sequence number (`index` property) to each of them (first item will have `"index": 1`, second `"index": 2`, etc.). So for this query:

```
db.items.aggregate([{ $sort: { "value": 1 } }])
```

result should be:

```
{ "name": "Second", "value": 2, "index": 1 },
{ "name": "Third", "value": 5, "index": 2 },
{ "name": "First", "value": 8, "index": 3 }
```

This should also works with `$skip`. With `{ "$skip": 1 }`, result should be items with indexes `2, 3`, not `1, 2`. Is there any way to do this using pure MongoDB, without any application logic?

Comment: Is your problem skipping the sort output or adding a number to sort result?

Comment: @Gibbs Adding a number to sort result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** Inspired by @turvishal's answer to meet the below things

1. Index starting from 1
2. Skip the way OP wants

[Mongo-play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3bSUvXA7hee)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      value: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: 1,
      items: {
        $push: {
          name: "$name",
          value: "$value"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$items",
      includeArrayIndex: "index"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: "$items.name",
      value: "$items.value",
      index: { //Incrementing the index by 1
        $add: [
          "$index",
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { //Addition of skip 
    "$skip": 1
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i really forgot to add `$add` operation, appreciated.

Comment: its ok i don't mind, OP should be satisfy with solution.

Answer (score 4):

Might be this is one option you can do with [includeArrayIndex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html#includearrayindex) in `$unwind`,

- `$sort` by value that you already did
- `$group` by `name` and `value` and push in `items`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `items` and set field `index` in `includeArrayIndex`
- `$project` required fields and increment index with because it start with `0` zero

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $sort: { value: 1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: 1,
      items: {
        $push: {
          name: "$name",
          value: "$value"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$items",
      includeArrayIndex: "index"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: "$items.name",
      value: "$items.value",
      index: { $add ["$index", 1] }
    }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/572ReIpRcl6